Could not get WP user data for a custom field on user's Profile page
I have tried over the last 2 days without success to configure out the error of Telegram link on WP Single page. Here i1s what I have tried to achieve:

I removed and add some fields on user's profile page of WP using php codes in functions.php:
 if ( ! function_exists( 'modify_profile_fields' ) ) :

     function modify_profile_fields( $contactmethods ) {
         unset($contactmethods['facebook']);
         unset($contactmethods['youtube']);
         unset($contactmethods['linkedin']);
         unset($contactmethods['instagram']);
         unset($contactmethods['myspace']);
         unset($contactmethods['twitter']);
         unset($contactmethods['pinterest']);
         unset($contactmethods['soundcloud']);
         unset($contactmethods['tumblr']);
         unset($contactmethods['wikipedia']);

         $contactmethods['phone1'] = __( 'Phone 1' );
         $contactmethods['telegram1'] = __( 'Telegram username' );

         return $contactmethods;
     }
     add_filter('user_contactmethods','modify_profile_fields', 10, 1);

 endif;



They work perfectly correctly as intended.

However, there is errors of displaying the value of Telegram field when I try to retrieve data of the 2 last fields which are phone1 and telegram1 with the following codes on Single page of Wordpress (single.php):

a. Here is php part:
    <?php

    $curauth_id = get_current_user_id();

    $author_phone1 = get_the_author_meta('phone1', $curauth_id);  // Get data from phone1 field on profile page
    $phone_display1 = preg_replace("|\s|","",$author_phone1);     // Remove white space from phone number

    $telegram_input1 = get_the_author_meta('telegram1', $author_id);
    $telegram_username1 = str_replace('@', '', $telegram_input1);   // Remove @ from telegram username if it is entered by users

    ?>

b. Here is HTML part:
    {if !empty($author_phone1)}
      <button class="btn phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" style="color:#AF0404 !important;"></i><a href="tel:{$phone_display1}" target="_top"> Call</a></button>
    {/if}

    {if !empty($telegram_username1)}
      <button class="btn chat"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots" style="color:#892cdc !important;"></i><a href="https://t.me/{$telegram_username1}" target="_top"> Chat</a></button>
    {/if}

The above HTML codes will display two buttons:
    Call    Chat

When hovering or clicking over Call button, it works perfectly as intended
When hovering or clicking over Chat button, it shows or go to: https://t.me/Array - it means the php codes above does not retrieve the value of Telegram1 field or something not right with curly codes?
Very appreciate any support.

FYI: Nesting a into button, or the other way around, is not allowed in HTML.

The text Array is what you get, when you force an array into a string context. So your $telegram_username1 apparently is not a string value here, but an array. Make a debug output using var_dump, to see what it actually contains.

I have tried  to debug them using many ways today without success. My question is why phone1 is a string while telegram1 is an array instead. Both are created in the same way in functions.php and their data are retrieved with the same way too. I am blind; can u please advise a bit details

Please double check the $author_id, it's undefined.

$author_id needs to be $curauth_id - is my first guess.

I have tested using var_dump(), and found out that telegram1 has no string "", while phone1 has a correct string. What is wrong, they are both created and displayed in the same way?

I used these: $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
     $author_phone1 = get_the_author_meta('phone1', $user_ID);
     echo '<pre>' , var_dump($author_phone1) , '</pre>';
     $telegram_input1 = get_the_author_meta('telegram1', $user_ID);
     echo '<pre>' , var_dump($telegram_input1) , '</pre>';  to test. $user_ID is defined


It means there is nothing wrong with curly codes as var_dump() test is conducted in pure php with 

WOW: I found out that words such as Telegram, telegram1, etc. are not allowed to be used as css id and name of a custom field of profile form on WP Profile page; it could be a trick made by WP itself or my WP Theme for single page. When I change telegram1 to email2, it works perfectly as intended. Anyone believes it?
Here are my fully working codes:

I removed and add some fields on user's profile page of WP using php codes in functions.php:
 if ( ! function_exists( 'modify_profile_fields' ) ) :

     function modify_profile_fields( $contactmethods ) {
         unset($contactmethods['facebook']);
         unset($contactmethods['youtube']);
         unset($contactmethods['linkedin']);
         unset($contactmethods['instagram']);
         unset($contactmethods['myspace']);
         unset($contactmethods['twitter']);
         unset($contactmethods['pinterest']);
         unset($contactmethods['soundcloud']);
         unset($contactmethods['tumblr']);
         unset($contactmethods['wikipedia']);

         $contactmethods['phone1'] = __( 'Phone 1' );
         $contactmethods['email2'] = __( 'Telegram username' );

         return $contactmethods;
     }
     add_filter('user_contactmethods','modify_profile_fields', 10, 1);

 endif;


Codes on WP single page (single.php)


a. Here is php part:
    <?php

    $curauth_id = get_current_user_id();

    $author_phone1 = get_the_author_meta('phone1', $curauth_id);  // Get data from phone1 field on profile page
    $phone_display1 = preg_replace("|\s|","",$author_phone1);     // Remove white space from phone number

    $telegram_input1 = get_the_author_meta('email2', $author_id);
    $telegram_username1 = str_replace('@', '', $telegram_input1);   // Remove @ from telegram username if it is entered by users

    ?>

b. Here is HTML part:
    {if !empty($author_phone1)}
      <button class="btn phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" style="color:#AF0404 !important;"></i><a href="tel:{$phone_display1}" target="_top"> Call</a></button>
    {/if}

    {if !empty($telegram_username1)}
      <button class="btn chat"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots" style="color:#892cdc !important;"></i><a href="https://t.me/{$telegram_username1}" target="_top"> Chat</a></button>
    {/if}

